# muxing overhead when convert .wav to .ogg using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav, ogg

I want to convert .wav file to .ogg file using ffmpeg, the command line order as follow:

```
ffmpeg.exe -acodec pcm_s16le -i audio.wav -acodec libvorbis audio.ogg
```

then it tells muxing overhead and the duration of the output .ogg is not right as well
[image: output infomation]

Is anyone know the reason, thanks!

you can download the audio file that I used from here:
[audio.wav](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p-X1GzxZbyln-t4o4wVwoIye1mKkbcIK/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: How was this WAV generated? Its codec tag is 0xffff i.e. development codec.

Comment: I extracted it from a .pck file

Comment: Which codec or game is it from?

Comment: Assassins Creed Odyssey

Comment: use Dragon UnPACKer

to extract it

Comment: @Gyan what development codec mean? and is there any way to solve this problem?